Typescript - How to make recursive interface for linked list?
Below is the nested repetitive data like linked list. I want to make interface for below data for nested objects:
interface List{
     data : number,
     next : Record<string,Record<string,string | number>> | null
   }

let Node:List = {
   data  : 1,
   next : {
    data : 2,
    next : null
 }
}


By "repetitive" do you mean "recursive"? If so you might want to [edit] to use the conventional terminology.

Below is the interface:
interface LinkedList {
  data: number;
  next: LinkedList | null;
}

const node: LinkedList = {
  data: 1,
  next: {
    data: 3,
    next: {
      data: 1,
      next: null
    }
  }
};

